# How much overhead is associated with an Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

In Android land, Fragments are aware of the Android lifecycle and are not destroyed when an activity is recreated. Because of this, I have seen people using empty fragments to get around issues with the Android lifecycle destroying references to background tasks and prevent leaks associated with keeping references to activities.

I was wondering how much overhead is associated with using Fragments as hooks to background tasks? I assume that Android decides not to destroy fragments because they are expensive to recreate (could be wrong).

Bonus question. Is there a way we can measure this cost? (maybe implementing alternate methods and checking resource utilisation).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a 'headless fragment' for background work.

The correct way is to use a `Loader` or `Service` (or `Intent Service`) depending on the duration and type of work that needs to be done.

In terms of overhead, I don't think there is much. You can create 4 apps with these 4 methods and profile them if you want, but the better approach is to pick a method that works for the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use `Fragment`s to keep tasks alive!
That will do more harm than use.

If you have tasks running long enough that you have to worry if they get killed, run them in a `Service`.

This is exactly what a `Service` (or `Loader`) is for. `Fragment`s should represent a part of your layout, not be used headless.

There is no reason to hack around if a working and intended solution exists.

Comment: In what way will it do more harm? These tasks are not applicable for service work. I would prefer to use loaders but have been told to avoid them.

Comment: You create a unintuitive construct, which might not work in the future. Also other programmers will have a hard time understanding your code. Even though it might work now, it will probably cost time in the future. Also there is no task which can be run in an AsyncTask, but not in a service.

Comment: I agree completely. I came across this pattern and tried to get my colleagues to convince me it was not a dirty hack. I am still not convinced haha.